# How to read multiline argument in Ansible

Tags: ansible, arguments, multiline

I pass a multiline variable called host_list from Jenkins to ansible which contains the list of hosts.

I need to read each host line by line and add it to ansible's add_host module.

Below is how my multiline argument looks like.

```
ansible-playbook /app/upgrade_tomcat.yml -i /tmp/inventory1775725953939119720.ini -t validate -f 5 -e tomcat_home=/app/tomcat -e host_list='10.9.9.19
10.9.55.16
10.9.44.26
' -e USER=user1
```

I tried the below but it does not work.

```
---
- name: "Find the details here"

  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - add_host: name={{ item }}
               groups=dest_nodes
               ansible_user={{ USER }}
     with_items: "{{ host_list.split('\n') }}"
```

I even tried the following:

```
host_list.splitlines()
host_list.split( )
```

But none of them works.

Requesting suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: this is absolutely ugly and should be replaced by any other correct way to acheive your result (non exhaustively including: defining your host list in a group in your inventory, including a file containing a definition of your list in yaml/json, passing var as extra var directly in yaml/json....)

After this warning, here is a working solution with your current situation. Simply quote values correctly.

**The command**

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e 'my_list="toto
pipo
bingo"'
```

**The playbook**

```
---
- name: Passing abolutely ugly vars on command line
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Split ugly extra var
      debug:
        msg: "{{ my_list.splitlines() }}"
```

The result:

```
PLAY [Passing abolutely ugly vars on command line] ***********************************************************

TASK [Split ugly extra var] **************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "toto",
        "pipo",
        "bingo"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Please understand that i have no control over the arguments of host names passed. The hostnames are read by multi string parameter of Jenkins is passed to Ansible again using Jenkins Ansible plugin -> advance -> extra variable. What i shared is just the output of how these products and plugins pass the variable. I tried your suggestion but it seems when added to add_host the first ip gets the double quotes and Ansible gives could not resolve hostname error. ["10.9.9.19] . See the quote causing the issue. Also the last host is the ["] which is again invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass as an array in extra-vars as below

```
-e '{"host_list": [10.9.9.19,10.9.55.16,10.9.44.26]}'
```

But it is always good to add them in the inventory as a group and use the group name in playbook

```
Inventory:
[host_list]
10.9.9.19
10.9.55.16
10.9.44.26
```

Use below to loop through each host

```
with_items: "{{ groups['host_list'] }}"
```

Comment: I have no control over how to pass the extra vars. I had selected inline content with dynamic inventory checked and content textbok as $host_list for inventory in the Jenkins Ansible plugin